# How to use background threads sequentially the correct way?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, background-process

Currently, my app uses one background thread in the method to iterate through the list of some items and based on that item type I am adding more information to it using other methods and then storing the new data in the Array List. Then when the background thread finished I am informed about that by the Handler and I am using the  ".notifyDataSetChanged() inside the Handler".

The main disadvantage of calling the  ".notifyDataSetChanged()" is that takes 10 seconds to display 400 items in the recycler view.

My goal here is to use all background threads sequentially with one main background thread to iterate through the list of some items and add more information to it using other methods that have to have sequential background threads also to get more information from the SugarORM database. Every background thread must communicate with the UI thread safely for instance by using Handler. The reason for that is that the handler then can use ".notifyItemChanged(_position)" and that hopefully can shrink the time to display from 10 seconds to much less.

The code below is my test code where I try to implement the background threads sequentially, however, that does not work correctly at the moment.

```
ThreadGroup mMainThreadForLoopThreadGroup;
ThreadGroup mThreadGroupMethodOne;
ThreadGroup mThreadGroupMethodTwo;



onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      callMainThread();
    }

private void callMainThread() {
    mMainThreadForLoopThreadGroup = new ThreadGroup("mMainThreadForLoopThreadGroup");
    startMainThreadForLoop(mMainThreadForLoopThreadGroup, "mMainThreadForLoop");
}


private void startMainThreadForLoop(ThreadGroup _threadGroup, String _threadName) {
    if (_threadName != null && !_threadName.isEmpty() && _threadGroup!=null) {
        final String mThreadName = _threadName;
        Thread mThread = new Thread(_threadGroup, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Message mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String mDateString = mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + " /startMainThreadForLoop";
                mBundle.putString("messageString", mDateString);
                mBundle.putBoolean(_threadName + "Boolean", true);
                try {
                    for (int n=0; n<=4; n++) {
                        if (n % 2==0){
                            methodOne();
                    } else {
                            methodTwo();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                mMessage.setData(mBundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
            }
        }, mThreadName);
        mThread.start();
    }
}

private void methodOne() {
    mThreadGroupMethodOne = new ThreadGroup("mThreadGroupMethodOne");
    for (int n=0; n<=4; n++) {
        if (n % 2==0){
            startThreadMethodOneA(mThreadGroupMethodOne, "mThreadMethodOneA");
        } else {
            startThreadMethodOneB(mThreadGroupMethodOne, "mThreadMethodOneB");
        }
    }
}

private void methodTwo() {
    mThreadGroupMethodTwo = new ThreadGroup("mThreadGroupMethodTwo");
    for (int n=0; n<=4; n++) {
        if (n % 2==0){
            startThreadMethodTwoA(mThreadGroupMethodTwo, "mThreadMethodTwoA");
        } else {
            startThreadMethodTwoB(mThreadGroupMethodTwo, "mThreadMethodTwoB");
        }
    }
}


private void startThreadMethodOneA(ThreadGroup _threadGroup, String _threadName) {
    if (_threadName != null && !_threadName.isEmpty() && _threadGroup!=null) {
        final String mThreadName = _threadName;
        Thread mThread = new Thread(_threadGroup, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Message mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String mDateString = mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + " /startThreadMethodOneA";
                mBundle.putString("messageString", mDateString);
                mBundle.putBoolean(_threadName + "Boolean", true);
                try {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                mMessage.setData(mBundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
            }
        }, mThreadName);
        mThread.start();
    }
}


private void startThreadMethodOneB(ThreadGroup _threadGroup, String _threadName) {
        if (_threadName != null && !_threadName.isEmpty() && _threadGroup!=null) {
            final String mThreadName = _threadName;
            Thread mThread = new Thread(_threadGroup, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Message mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                    String mDateString = mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + " /startThreadMethodOneB";
                    mBundle.putString("messageString", mDateString);
                    mBundle.putBoolean(_threadName + "Boolean", true);
                    try {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    mMessage.setData(mBundle);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
                }
            }, mThreadName);
            mThread.start();

        }
    }


private void startThreadMethodTwoA(ThreadGroup _threadGroup, String _threadName) {
    if (_threadName != null && !_threadName.isEmpty() && _threadGroup!=null) {
        final String mThreadName = _threadName;
        Thread mThread = new Thread(_threadGroup, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Message mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String mDateString = mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + " /startThreadMethodTwoA";
                mBundle.putString("messageString", mDateString);
                mBundle.putBoolean(_threadName + "Boolean", true);
                try {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                mMessage.setData(mBundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
            }
        }, mThreadName);
        mThread.start();
    }
}


private void startThreadMethodTwoB(ThreadGroup _threadGroup, String _threadName) {
        if (_threadName != null && !_threadName.isEmpty() && _threadGroup!=null) {
            final String mThreadName = _threadName;
            Thread mThread = new Thread(_threadGroup, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Message mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                    String mDateString = mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + " /startThreadMethodTwoB";
                    mBundle.putString("messageString", mDateString);
                    mBundle.putBoolean(_threadName + "Boolean", true);
                    try {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    mMessage.setData(mBundle);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(mMessage);
                }
            }, mThreadName);
            mThread.start();
        }
    }


@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle mBundle = msg.getData();
        String mNewString = mBundle.getString("messageString");
        boolean mBooleanMainThreadForLoopValue = mBundle.getBoolean("mMainThreadForLoopBoolean");
        boolean mBooleanThreadMethodOneAValue = mBundle.getBoolean("mThreadMethodOneABoolean");
        boolean mBooleanThreadMethodOneBValue = mBundle.getBoolean("mThreadMethodOneBBoolean");
        boolean mBooleanThreadMethodTwoAValue = mBundle.getBoolean("mThreadMethodTwoABoolean");
        boolean mBooleanThreadMethodTwoBValue = mBundle.getBoolean("mThreadMethodTwoBBoolean");
        if (mBooleanMainThreadForLoopValue) {
            if (mBundle.getString("messageString")!=null &&
                    !mBundle.getString("messageString").isEmpty() ) {
                Log.d("Handler Response", "\nmMainThreadForLoopBoolean Finished, value: " +
                        mBundle.getString("messageString"));
                dateTextView.setText(mBundle.getString("messageString"));
            }
        } else if (mBooleanThreadMethodOneAValue) {
            if (mBundle.getString("messageString")!=null &&
                    !mBundle.getString("messageString").isEmpty() ) {
                Log.d("Handler Response", "\nmThreadMethodOneABoolean Finished, value: " +
                        mBundle.getString("messageString"));
                dateTextViewSecond.setText(mBundle.getString("messageString"));
            }
        } else if (mBooleanThreadMethodOneBValue) {
            if (mBundle.getString("messageString")!=null &&
                    !mBundle.getString("messageString").isEmpty() ) {
                Log.d("Handler Response", "\nmThreadMethodOneBBoolean Finished, value: " +
                        mBundle.getString("messageString"));
                dateTextViewSecond.setText(mBundle.getString("messageString"));
            }
        } else if (mBooleanThreadMethodTwoAValue) {
            if (mBundle.getString("messageString")!=null &&
                    !mBundle.getString("messageString").isEmpty() ) {
                Log.d("Handler Response", "\nmThreadMethodTwoABoolean Finished, value: " +
                        mBundle.getString("messageString"));
                dateTextViewSecond.setText(mBundle.getString("messageString"));
            }
        } else if (mBooleanThreadMethodTwoBValue) {
            if (mBundle.getString("messageString")!=null &&
                    !mBundle.getString("messageString").isEmpty() ) {
                Log.d("Handler Response", "\nmThreadMethodTwoBBoolean Finished, value: " +
                        mBundle.getString("messageString"));
                dateTextViewSecond.setText(mBundle.getString("messageString"));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You posted too much not really relevant code and it makes almost impossible to break through easily. Please consider to simplify your question. With that said, it sounds wrong that some operation takes as much as 10 seconds; I would definitely to try to profile what's going on.

Comment: The live app has more than 500 lines of code, for that reason, I simplify the code so everyone can copy/paste the code and try it.

My question is simple: "How to use background threads sequentially the correct way?"

In my example, I am using "for loop" to check if the thread is running sequentially or not and to check that I am using the Handler that shows the result in the "Log.d".

I am not sure how to  "profile what's going on". I know that from the point when the code reache notifyDataSetChanged() to the point to display the data in the recycler view takes 10 seconds for 400 items.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I did not run your code, but in the comments you say that:

> My question is simple: "How to use background threads sequentially the correct way?"

The answer is: that's plain wrong. Threads concept is all about doing things *in parallel* which is by the definition confronts a *sequential* execution. Multithreading suppose to be non-sequential by it's nature (except relevantly small pieces of code named "critical sections" which indeed must run sequentially otherwise you gonna get a "race condition" and a broken program).

If you want number of tasks to be processed *strictly sequentially*, you *do not* use multiple threads, rather you re-use a single one that does the processing in the one-by-one fashion. Sequentially.

---

If you find this answer misleading or not related, then please, ask more questions in the comments and I will update my answer with more details.